# Adding items inside combobox column on datagridview and click dropdown

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, combobox

I have a combobox column on my datagridview that is on my winforms(c#) and I put items to it in design time but when I run the program I can't click on the dropdown of the combobox column (first column) its like a disabled combobox column and I can't see the items I put inside. what seems to be the problem there?

I have tried so many codes I get from this site and other sites but none of them worked. I also tried to set TRUE value for the readonly property of the first column of the datagridview which is the combobox column but same result

Comment: hi hamza, can you give me an idea to solve my problem for combobox column? thank you. highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I believe you already tested and confirmed that the combobox works fine when it is alone.

I can think of two possibilities: A) the combobox is not receiving any mouse hit event. B) the combobox received mouse hit event but makes not reaction.

We firstly check if it is caused by possibility A. One way to test this, is to temporarily add a simple mouse hit event method to this combobox (such as popping up a messagebox or adding a console log when mouse hit event is triggered).

=> If the mouse hit event is actually triggered, it shows possibility A is wrong, and the cause should be B. Then please check if the combobox or its parent container/control are disabled (disabled UI elements can still trigger mouse hit event, but they will not react since they are disabled).

=> If the mouse hit event is confirmed not triggered, then there are two more possible sub-scenarios:

- 1: The combobox is "transparent" to mouse hit event. To fix this, you set its IsHitTestVisible to true.
- 2: The combobox's parent container/control has "blocked" the mouse hit event. To test this, you replace the combobox with a normal button and see if it is not reactive neither. If so, this scenario is proven, thus you need to trace the hierarchy of its parent container/control and see where the mouse hit event is "blocked".